# How to fix The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am trying to insert data from another database and this code was working until today. Now it doesn't anymore.

Here is the code:

```
var itemMember = Db.Members.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == CurrentMember.Id);
var itemSelectedName = Db.Topics.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == TopicId);
var itemMap = Db.Reeves.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Member.Id == CurrentMember.Id);
var itemReeve = Db.Reeves.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Member.Id == CurrentMember.Id);
var item = new Problem
      {
          Name = input.Name,
          Text = input.Info,
          Topic = itemSelectedName,
          WhoIs = itemMember,
          Province = itemMap.Province,
          District = itemMap.District,
          Town = itemMap.Town,
          Reeve=itemReeve,
          Created=DateTime.Now,
          Solved = false,
          Read=false
      };

Db.Problems.Add(item);
Db.SaveChanges();
```

There is nothing null in the code and it throws an error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

What should I do ?

Also this error shows up now:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.

but as I said it was working till today :/

Here is view model:

```
[Display(Name = "Başlık"), Required, StringLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Bilgi")]
[UIHint("TinyMCE")]
public string Info { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Gerekli Alan")]
[Display(Name = "Konu")]
[UIHint("DropDownList")]
[AdditionalMetadata("DataController", "Problem")]
[AdditionalMetadata("DataAction", "ProblemDrop")]
public int? TopicId { get; set; }
```

Here is model

```
public class Problem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public short Sira { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
    public virtual Member WhoIs { get; set; }
    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
    public virtual Town Town { get; set; }
    public virtual District District { get; set; }
    public virtual Reeve Reeve { get; set; }
    public Boolean Solved { get; set; }
    public DateTime SolvedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Member WhoSolved { get; set; }
    public Boolean Read { get; set; }
}
```

Solved: Date is null could it be the problem ?

Comment: Does you model contain any other `DateTime` properties?

Comment: Posting your model class would be helpful.

Comment: I have updated the model and viewmodel @StephenMuecke

Comment: I have updated the question @jjczopek

Comment: Your database field for `SolvedDate` is DATETIME which only supports dates for years 1753-9999. If you don't set a value for `SolvedDate`, the default is `1/1/0001` which is out of range. You can change the database field to DATETIME2 but it looks like it really should be nullable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not set a value for `SolvedDate`, so the default value which is `01\01\01` will be sent to the database, which causes the error.

If you want to have `SolvedDate` with `null` value, you should define it as `Nullable` date(`DateTime?`) because `DateTime` is a `struct` and cannot be set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

That error appears when you try to insert invalid date into `datetime` field in DB. Check this field in `Problem` model:

```
public DateTime SolvedDate { get; set; }
```

This should be made `null` or initialized to some value.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error after creating a new viewmodel.  I changed my DateTime field(s) to nullable (DateTime?) in the viewmodel and it solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In addition to providing an explanation for what worked for you also include some code to help future users resolve their questions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in ASP.NET, when making the field nullable was not an option:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
}
```